# A good reference to the fact that unitary transforms map normal vectors to normal vectors?

Tags: probability, statistics

More precisely: given a vector of independent, standard normally distributed random variables, if we apply a unitary transform we obtain again a vector of independent, standard normally distributed random variables.

A good reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X$ is multivariate normal and $A$ is any real matrix, we can let $Y=AX$ and obtain a multivariate normal $Y$ with

$E[Y]=AE[X]$

and

$\mbox{Cov}(Y)=A \; \mbox{Cov}(X) A^{T}$.

If $X$ is a standard normal ($N(0,I)$), and $A$ is an orthogonal matrix matrix, then $E[X]=0$, so $E[Y]=A0=0$, and $\mbox{Cov}(Y)=AIA^{T}=I$.  Thus $Y$ is $N(0,I)$.

This is discussed in many textbooks and references on mathematical statistics.  A reasonable starting point is the Wikipedia article on the multivariate normal distribution:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Affine_transformation

Comment: Thank you. I see now it is a very special case of a much more general result, which is why I was not able to find it simply by keyword search.

Comment: I've assumed that you're interested in real multivariate normal random variables and a real unitary (that is orthogonal) matrix A.  This becomes a bit more complicated if you want to deal with complex multivariate normal random vectors.

Comment: You assumed correctly.

Comment: For the complex case, see: http://www.rle.mit.edu/rgallager/documents/CircSymGauss.pdf